# ionic Date time picker show only the date (ng-cordova)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

i'm working with ionic framework to develop a web app . in this app i need a datetime picker so i instaled ng-cordova datepicker plugin , on android device it's works good but on ios device i get only the date without the time here is my code :

```
var options_date = {
 date: new Date(),
 mode: 'datetime', // or 'time'
 minDate: new Date() - 10000,
 allowOldDates: true,
 allowFutureDates: true,
 doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
 doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
 cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
 cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
};
$scope.setDate = function() {
  $cordovaDatePicker.show(options_date).then(function(date){
     $scope.startDateTime = date;
  });
};
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check with this code it is working for me: 
In index.html create a button as

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
      <button class="button button-bar button-balanced" ng-click="datePick()">Check It</button>
      </ion-content>
```

In your controller write the function code as:

```
.controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicPlatform','$cordovaDatePicker', function ($scope,$ionicPlatform,$cordovaDatePicker) {
  $scope.datePick = function(){
    var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'datetime', // or 'time'
    minDate: new Date() - 10000,
    allowOldDates: true,
    allowFutureDates: false,
    doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
    doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
    cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
    cancelButtonColor: '#000000'

    }
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
        alert(date);
      });

    })
  }

}])
```

Answer (score 0):

Android browser doesn't support (at the time being) the `datetime` HTML5 inputs type.

The [README page of the plugin](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) also says that `datetime` is only for iOs and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
mode: 'date'
```

and

```
mode: 'time'
```

in 2 controls and collect datetime from both values.